# Trying to implement a linear search on an ordered array for a specific number(n) but return statement keeps returning nothing

Tags: python

I am trying to perform a linear search on an ordered array for a specific number. If the number is found, the algorithm must return its index. If we reach an element that is greater than the number, the algorithm should break. Lastly, if the number is not in the array print `None`. When I run the code, it returns no output. I have tried different variations of even including the number I am looking for in the array but the code still produces no output.

```
def linear_search(array, number):
    for el in range(len(array)):
        if el == number:
            return array[el]
        elif el > number:
            break
        else:
            return None

print(linear_search([10,11,12,22],22))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no output"? When I run this code, I get `None`. If you get nothing, you might be running the wrong script. Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say None. Using the suggested solutions worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

- You should be checking `if array[el] == number`
- `return None` outside of the IF statement, otherwise it will return `None` when `el == 0`

Comment: In addition to `if array[el] == number`, `elif array[el] > number`

Comment: Yes, this looked like a homework problem so I was trying to suggest help, not give it all away. But ya know. ‍♂️

Comment: using your approach array[el] worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Would you please accept my solution so I can get the reputation points? =D

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you out!

```
    def LinearSearch(array, n, k):
    for j in range(0,n):
        if (array[j] == k):
            return j
    return -1

array = [10,20,30,40,50]
k = 30
n = len(array)
result = LinearSearch(array, n, k)    
if (result == -1):
    print("Element not found")
else:
    print("Element found at index:", result)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def linear_search(array, number):
    for el in range(len(array)):
        if array[el] == number:
            return el
    return None
```

Comment: This is good but don't forget to break if the array entry is higher than number. CS instructors are very specific when they give assignments like this. :o